# Does AJAX function call within regular intervals would slow down the application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In my application in a particular page I use an AJAX function call continuously like below,

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
        $(document).ready(function(){   


            setInterval(function() {
                 $.ajax({  
                    url:'clmcontrol_livematchupdate',
                    type:'post', 
                    dataType: 'json',  
                    success: function(data) {  


                        $('#lblbattingteam').html(data.battingnow);
                        $('#lblscore').html(data.score);
                        $('#lblwickets').html(data.wickets);
                        $('#lblovers').html(data.overs);
                        $('#lblballs').html(data.balls);
                        $('#lblextras').html(data.extras);
                        $('#lblrr').html(data.runrate);

                        $('#lblbowlingteam').html(data.bowlingnow);
                        $('#lblbowler').html(data.currentbowler);
                        $('#lblbowlerovers').html(data.bowlerovers);
                        $('#lblbowlerballs').html(data.bowlerballs);
                        $('#lblrunsgiven').html(data.runsgiven);
                        $('#lblextrasgiven').html(data.extrasgiven);
                        $('#lblwicketstaken').html(data.wicketstaken);
                        $('#lblecon').html(data.econ);


                    }  
                });  
            }, 4000);
        });  
    </script>
```

Any how at the first attempts the application ran well and the values got updated as I expected, but after few attempts more the values struggled to update and going further updates were not happening. Is it because the function slows down the system due to continuous ajax calls?

Comment: I would assume the system could handle a single ajax call every 4 seconds, unless a LOT of people are using the same script.

Comment: One suggestion: Unless the values actually contain HTML that needs to be parsed, use `.text()` instead of `.html()`. Inserting text without parsing should be faster.

Comment: `ajax` isn't immediate. so for slow connections, `setInterval` will queue up ajax calls before prior ones have finished. Use a callback queue instead.

Comment: @zzzzBov How would I do that? Please can u explain a bit since I'm new to AJAX

Comment: Alternatively, instead of using a polling system, use WebSockets to open a direct connection to the server.

Comment: Use `timeout` in your `always` callback, instead of `interval`. never use interval for async

Answer (score 1):

It's better not to use setInterval() because If the first request hasn't completed and start another one, you could end up in a situation where you have multiple requests that consume shared resources and starve each other. You can avoid this problem by waiting to schedule the next request until the last one has completed.

Just Try:

```
(function ajaxInterval() {
      $.ajax({  
                url:'clmcontrol_livematchupdate',
                type:'post', 
                dataType: 'json',  
                success: function(data) {  


                    $('#lblbattingteam').html(data.battingnow);
                    $('#lblscore').html(data.score);
                    $('#lblwickets').html(data.wickets);
                    $('#lblovers').html(data.overs);
                    $('#lblballs').html(data.balls);
                    $('#lblextras').html(data.extras);
                    $('#lblrr').html(data.runrate);

                    $('#lblbowlingteam').html(data.bowlingnow);
                    $('#lblbowler').html(data.currentbowler);
                    $('#lblbowlerovers').html(data.bowlerovers);
                    $('#lblbowlerballs').html(data.bowlerballs);
                    $('#lblrunsgiven').html(data.runsgiven);
                    $('#lblextrasgiven').html(data.extrasgiven);
                    $('#lblwicketstaken').html(data.wicketstaken);
                    $('#lblecon').html(data.econ);


                },
                complete: function() {
                  // Schedule the next request when the current one has been completed
                  setTimeout(ajaxInterval, 4000);
                }  
            });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a potential issue here that would be obvious if you checked your network calls from a debugger. Due to the non blocking async behavior of the ajax call you have the potential to be making simultaneous ajax calls. Depending on your browser you are only allowed to make so many calls at the same time so they will queue up. In these circumstances there are also no guarantees of execution order.

In your situation I would set `async: false` in the ajax options. You are already gaining non interface blocking behavior by executing in the setInterval callback. Since setInterval just applies a timer in between method calls you will never have more than one ajax call operating at a given time(which is a likely culprit of your issue).